# Shortcuts failing constantly

Tags: macos, keyboard, adobe

I am using Adobe Audition. I have defined a few shortcuts for functions I use the most. These shortcuts work sometimes, sometimes don't.

This is also true for shortcuts I have defined for other applications.

When these shortcuts fail, I click on the menu where their respective functions are and then if I try the shortcuts again they work but seconds later they fail again.

Is there a way to make they always work?

Comment: What is the version of macOS that you are using?

Comment: Adobe software uses Adobe's own shortcut structure, not Apple's [unless Audition is different, I only use the graphics stuff] but knowing which apps & which versions [cos if you're running CS6 on High Sierra then nothing would surprise me], where you set the key combos...etc...

Comment: show us an example of shortcuts in "other" applications. are they conflicting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would happen if you set up Shortcuts to work in "All Applications"

Try setting them Application Specific.

Example

[image]

[image]

Alternately monitor the `com.apple.systempreferences.plist`

located in `~/Library/Preferences` and sort by date, to see if it changes without your interaction.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I did that now but the problem persists. Works 20% of the time and like I said, it is not just audition. It fails equally for all apps I have tested.

Comment: so you have someone overwriting your Preferences ? give some time to check on that.

Comment: do you use apps like MagicPrefs or Onyx or similar ?

Comment: I'm still worried about Adobe preferring to do its own shortcuts... clarification of my comment above would be nice...

Comment: in your Finder go to ~/Library/Preferences and sort by date, and see which plist file is latest and when it changed.

Comment: also on a hunch ... close iCloud (log out)

Comment: @Buscar웃, No difference for all your suggestions. Thanks anyway. First file to write is com.apple.universalaccess.plist and after that com.adobe.Audition.plist. I will install mojave right now and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: As no Adobe app will appear in the Apps list for shortcuts...because Adobe **does its own shortcuts**, as already mentioned... I'm still totally confused as to how the OP has achieved the initial claim. Anyway, as we've had no actually useful input other than to state your solution didn't work, I guess we may never know.